# Python Watchdog and Python ffmpeg module not working together! Why is my on_created Event of Python Watchdog not fired?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am downloading facebook page videos via youtube-dl package. To get the .mp4 in max resolution, I need to download audio and video serperatly. In order to merge audio and video, I use ffmpeg, which works perfectly.
Some videos are in low resolution, so they do not have seperate audio... but they are just one file. I am getting those as well. In this case, I do not need to merge them via ffmpeg.
This is my the code:

```
 ydl_opts = {"format":"bestvideo/best","outtmpl":"%(id)s.%(ext)s", "ignoreerrors":True}
    try:
            
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            
            ydl.download([videoLink])
            
            info= ydl.extract_info(videoLink, download=False, process=True)
        
         
            videoTitleMapping[info['id']]=title
            
            
            

                
                
            if os.path.isfile(f"{info['id']}.mp4"):
                input_video = ffmpeg.input(f"{info['id']}.mp4")
            else:
                input_video = ffmpeg.input(f"{info['id']}.webm")
                    
                    
        ydl_opts = {"format":"bestaudio/best","outtmpl":"%(id)s.%(ext)s", "ignoreerrors":True}

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([videoLink])
            print(videoLink)
            info= ydl.extract_info(videoLink, download=False, process=True)
            
            if os.path.isfile(f"{info['id']}.m4a"):
                input_audio = ffmpeg.input(f"{info['id']}.m4a")
            
            
        
            if os.path.isfile(f"./merged/{info['id']}.mp4"):
                print("File already downloaded")
            else:
                if input_audio==None:
                    if os.path.isfile(f"{info['id']}.webm"):
                        shutil.move(f"{info['id']}.webm", f"./merged/{info['id']}.webm")
                    else:
                        shutil.move(f"{info['id']}.mp4", f"./merged/{info['id']}.mp4")
                else:
                    print('prossing')
                    if input_video and input_audio:    
                        ffmpeg.concat(input_video, input_audio, v=1, a=1).output(f"./merged/{info['id']}.mp4").run()
                        shutil.move(f"./merged/{info['id']}.mp4", f"./processed/{info['id']}.mp4")
                        # os.rename(f"./processed/{info['id']}.mp4",f"./processed/{info['id']}.tmp")
                        
    except:
        print('failed')
        
        
    finally:
        print('Done')
```

It works perfectly.

I tried to experiment with watchdog, this is why I used

```
shutil.move(f"./merged/{info['id']}.mp4", f"./processed/{info['id']}.mp4")
```

in the end... but thats not so imporant. Why I want to archive is the following,

after processing via ffmpeg, the file gets put in a directory, in this case the "processed" folder.
Now I want Python watchdog to watch this folder via "on_created" and do something whenever there is a file. And that "something" is to upload it to youtube. Unfortunately, the on_created event is never fired. Does someone know why? Here is the code:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os
import videoUpload
tikTokOrFacebook=input('You want to download videos from Facebook or TikTok? Type "Facebook" or "TikTok"')
if tikTokOrFacebook=='Facebook':
    import fb_dl
else:
 import tik_dl

class  Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    print('handler called')
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
  
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            for filename in os.listdir(folder_destination):
                if '.mp4' in filename:
                    print(folder_to_track)
                    src = folder_to_track + '\\' +filename
                    new_dest = folder_destination + '\\' + filename
                    vidId= filename.split('.mp4')[0]
                    videoUpload.getVideoMetaData(vidId)
                    print(filename)
            print('createdEvent')   
folder_to_track=os.getcwd()

folder_destination=os.getcwd()+'\\processed\\'


event_handler = Handler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)

observer.start()

    
try:
    while True:
        print('jfhdjfhdjfhdjfhd')
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Does this have something to do with ffmpeg... because I am able to upload videos that are directly downloaded from tiktok without any processing via ffmpeg. The files are just put in the "processed" folder and then the on_created event is fired.

Comment: Do we really need all the stories about Facebook, YouTube and TikTok? Can you reproduce the problem by simply creating synthetic video: `ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg.input('testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10', f='lavfi'), 'tmp.mp4').overwrite_output().run()`? Are you sure the video does not exist in the destination folder, and FFmpeg doesn't ask you `File ... already exists. Overwrite? [y/N]`?

Comment: Thx for your reply Rotem.  Haha, I actually do not need all that stuff from those social media plattform, but a client wants me to write some sort of scraper for him :) 
You want me to try output instead of concat... and with the overwrite_output() method?
Yes, I am 100% sure the destination folder is empty and ffmpeg does not ask me to overwrite it.

Comment: The `overwrite_output()` is not required if the destination folder is empty. The point is that you should try posting a minimal reproducible code sample (code we can execute, and verify the issue).

Comment: I understand... the problem is tho, that I am working with youtubeAPI and you would have to make some configurations, so that the script is verified to upload to a youtube account.  I can provide acccess to my github. We have 4 files there: fb_dl.py for downloading videos from fb, tik_dl for downloading videos from tiktok, videoUpload for uploading videos to youtube and test.py for calling the upload function from videoUpload.py when there is one in the "processed" directory. token.pickle and client_secrets.json are for auth of youtubeapi. heres my github repo:

Comment: https://github.com/thebeautyofcoding/py_downloader

Comment: Hmmm, I tried to comment out the ffmpeg.concat()... so that mp4 files without audio are put in the "processed" folder. watchdog on_created still doesnt fire. the only difference between tik_dl and fb_dl.py is that I use  with urllib.request.urlopen() in tik_dl while I use  ydl.download([videoLink]) in fb_dl.py So it might having something to do with the youtube-dl package? :(